# React-Native create button when other button's onPress Event

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I want the button to be dynamically created and used when the onPress event occurs. Ask for help from great and kind friends.

I want
{ in screen one Button , -> Button click -> create one Button -> so we have two button }

it is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
const Test = () => { 
    return( 
        <Button title='test' onPress={<Button title='test1'/>}/> 
    ) 
} 
export default Test
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
const Test = () => { 
    return( 
        <Button title='test' onPress={ButtonRender}/> 
    ) 
}
const ButtonRender =():any=>{
    return <Button title='test1'/>
}
export default Test
```

I have a problem. It is not created Button. I need help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742132/return-jsx-component-onpress-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render code inside `onPress` method.

```
onPress={ButtonRender}
```

This piece of code will not render the code to the virtual dom. Basically You can't return value from `onPress` instead you can change the state of component this causes the component to rerender.

So How you can resolve this(another approach) just an example Not tested it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button,Text } from 'react-native'
  function TestUseState() {

  const [buttonArr, setButtonArr] = React.useState([]);
const renderButtons = () =>{
  return buttonArr.map ((item,index)=> 
                         <Button key={index} title= "your title"> </Button > 
                       )
} 
  return (
    <>
      <Text>Buttons List</Text>
      {renderButtons()}
     <Button onPress={() => setButtonArr( [...buttonArr , "Unique Index of new Button"] )} title="Add Button"></Button> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This workaround creates a button but causes an error.
When the button is pressed, an error of'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.' occurs. Even if you put a value that changes by +1 in "Unique Index of new Button" and enter a unique key, an error occurs. I need help.

Comment: Answer Updated you should pass `key` props when you are mapping an array

Comment: I am curious if you are talking about'interface props{~~}'. If it is correct, I am wondering if I need to input the key in'~~' and put it in'map'
But I assigned a different value each time, but I got an error. Is there a difference from receiving user input?